# Listening to the coordinates of an animating element on Raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am currently working on a small scale game for my project. My goal is for the 'player' to navigate through a group of enemies without touching them. To make the player die, I intend to listen for the coordinates of the animating 'Circle' and look for an event whereby the distance between the player and the enemy is 0. Is there a way to listen to the animating coordinates of the circle because currently, it is listening to where my mouse clicked rather than where the circle actually is when it is animating.

```
bg.node.addEventListener("mousedown",function(ev){
console.log("mouse is down");
if(ev.button==2){
char.animate({
    'cx':ev.offsetX,
    'cy':ev.offsetY
},900,"linear")
charX = ev.offsetX;
charY=ev.offsetY;
```

}

let drawT = function(){

```
let n=0;
while(n<numDisk){
    diskT[n].xpos += diskT[n].xrate;
    diskT[n].ypos += diskT[n].yrate;

    // Now actually move the disk on screen using our 'state' variables
    diskT[n].attr({'cx': diskT[n].xpos, 'cy': diskT[n].ypos});

    // keep the object on the paper

    if (diskT[n].xpos > dimX)
    {diskT[n].xrate = -diskT[n].xrate};
    if (diskT[n].ypos > dimY) {
        diskT[n].ypos = dimY
        diskT[n].yrate = - diskT[n].yrate};
    if (diskT[n].xpos < 0)
    {diskT[n].xrate = -diskT[n].xrate};
    if (diskT[n].ypos < 0) {
        diskT[n].ypos = 0
        diskT[n].yrate = - diskT[n].yrate};

    if(distance(charX,diskT[n].xpos,charY,diskT[n].ypos)<=30){
        confirm("You died!");
```

These are my codes for animating the movement of the character and how I intend to make the character die. The disks in the array are the enemies.

Comment: Do you need to use Raphael ? Snap.svg is it's sister updated library (pretty much compatible and includes all svg elements), and you could possibly then use http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.animation which you can include a setter function which could do a testing each frame.

Comment: I am actually being assessed on the usage of Raphael so yes I need to use Raphael :')